# Which preposition should I use before "cells"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should be placed before "cells"?

in or on?
For example

The cytotoxicity of Doxorubicin in Hela cells?

The cytotoxicity of Doxorubicin on Hela cells?

or even

The cytotoxicity of Doxorubicin against/to/towards Hela cells?

Well, totally at a loss.

Is there any difference?

Comment: Had you thought of using "to" instead of in, on or against? To me it would seem more natural. Digitalis is toxic *to* humans, whereas gestation is nine months *in* humans. No doubt someone will be along presently who can explain why that may be.

Comment: Use whichever preposition best expresses your intent. For example, a cat can be on/beside/under/etc a mat. Which to pick depends on what was intended. Once you’ve figured out the intent, the preposition should follow fairly naturally.